# Prisma 1 + MongoDB Atlas deploy to Heroku returns error 404

Tags: mongodb, docker, heroku, graphql, prisma

I've deployed a *Prisma 1 GraphQL* server app on *Heroku*, connected to a *MongoDB Atlas* cluster.
Running `prisma deploy` locally with the default endpoint `http://localhost:4466`, the action being run successfully and all the schemas are being generated correctly.
But, if I change the endpoint with the Heroku remote host `https://<myapp>.herokuapp.com`, `prisma deploy` fails, returning this exception:

> ERROR: GraphQL Error (Code: 404)
> {
> "error": "\n<html lang="en">\n\n<meta charset="utf-8">\nError\n\n\n
>
> ```
> Cannot POST /management
> ```
>
> \n\n\n",
> "status": 404
> }

I think that's could be related to an authentication problem, but I'm getting confused because I've defined both security token in `prisma.yml` than the management API secret key in `docker-compose.yml`.
Here's my current configs if it could be helpful:

**prisma.yml**

```
# The HTTP endpoint for your Prisma API
# Tried with https://<myapp>.herokuapp.com only too with the same result
endpoint: https://<myapp>.herokuapp.com/dinai/staging
secret: ${env:PRISMA_SERVICE_SECRET}
# Points to the file that contains your datamodel
datamodel: datamodel.prisma
databaseType: document
# Specifies language & location for the generated Prisma client
generate:
  - generator: javascript-client
    output: ../src/generated/prisma-client
# Ensures Prisma client is re-generated after a datamodel change.
hooks:
  post-deploy:
    - prisma generate
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        managementApiSecret: ${PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET}
        databases:
          default:
            connector: mongo
            uri: mongodb+srv://${MONGO_DB_USER}:${MONGO_DB_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_DB_CLUSTER}/myapp?retryWrites=true&w=majority
            database: myapp
```

Plus, a weird situation happens too. In both cases, if I try to navigate the resulting API with *GraphQL Playground*, clicking on the tab "Schema" returns an error. On the other side, the tab "Docs" is being populated correctly. Apparently, seems that the exception is blocking the script finishing to generate the rest of the schemas.

A little help by someone experienced with Prisma/Heroku would be awesome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To date, I still do not clear what was causing the exception in detail. But looking deeply on Prisma docs, I discovered that in version 1 there's the necessity to proxy the app through the *Prisma Cloud*.
So probably, deploying straight on Heroku without it, was generating the main issue: basically there wasn't any Prisma container service running on the server.

What I did is to follow step by step the official doc about how to deploy your server on Prisma Cloud ([here's the video version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJe8YBs8Afg)). As in the example shown in the guide, I already have my own project, which is actually splitted in two different apps: respectively one for the client (front-end) and one for the API (back-end). So, instead to generate a new one, I pointed the back-end API endpoint to the remote URL of the Prisma server generated by the cloud (the Heroku container created by following the tutorial). Then, leaving the management secret API key only on the Prisma server container configuration (which has been generated automatically by the cloud) and, on the other hand, the service secret only on the back-end app, finally I was able to run the `prisma deploy` correctly and run my project remotely.